# How to get average in only 2 decimals using SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that gives the time to answer a call in seconds (without decimals). I would like to get the average time to answer (in seconds with two decimals) per month. I wrote code but I'm getting 6 decimals.

Where am I going wrong?

**My code:**

```
SELECT datepart(year,CallStartTime) [Year]
      ,datepart(month,CallStartTime) [Month]
      ,datepart(day,CallStartTime) [Day]
      ,AVG( CAST((TimeToAnswer) AS Decimal (10,2))) [Average]

FROM LineCallTracer LCT

WHERE LCT.CallStartTime >= '2017-10-01 00:00:00.000'
  AND LCT.DNIS = 5050
  AND LCT.MainDevice IS NOT NULL

GROUP BY datepart(year,CallStartTime), 
    datepart(month,CallStartTime), 
    datepart(day,CallStartTime)

ORDER BY [Year], [Month], [Day]
```

**The results I'm getting are as follows:**

```
Year    Month   Day   Average
2017    10       1    0.466666
2017    10       2    1.513036
2017    10       3    1.642029
2017    10       4    0.890945
2017    10       5    0.541231
2017    10       6    0.638501
```

How do I get the Average in only two decimals?

**EDIT:**
When I instead try two other options

```
,CAST( AVG(TimeToAnswer) AS Decimal (10,2)) [Average] 
           -- OR
,FORMAT(AVG(TimeToAnswer), '#########0.00') AS [Average]
```

then I get the following results (which is not accurate):

```
Year    Month   Day      Average
2017    10       1       0.00
2017    10       2       1.00
2017    10       3       1.00
2017    10       4       0.00
2017    10       5       0.00
2017    10       6       0.00
```

Comment: Try casting the result of `AVG` to `DECIMAL` instead. `CAST(AVG(TimeToAnswer)  AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) AS [Average]`

Comment: I tried that but got inaccurate results. I've posted it as an EDIT in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the following syntax and it worked. I used a mix of suggestions from @GordonLinoff and @ThorstenKettner. I have upvoted both their answers.

```
,FORMAT (AVG( CAST((TimeToAnswer) AS Decimal (10,2))), '#########0.00') [Average]
```

I am now getting the following results with automatic rounding up or down as necessary.

```
Year    Month   Day      Average
2017    10       1       0.47
2017    10       2       1.51
2017    10       3       1.64
2017    10       4       0.89
2017    10       5       0.54
2017    10       6       0.64
```

Comment: I was about to suggest this. What happens is that your column is defined as an integer column and SQL Server applies integer math on it. I always considered this a great weakness, but others may think different about this. So the avarage is calculated based on the type. With many records it may even make a difference, how many decimal places you cast to. To be on the save side I'd cast to `decimal(18,10)` or the like :-)

Answer (score 2):

Do the `cast()` after the average:

```
  CAST(AVG(TimeToAnswer) AS Decimal(10, 2)) as [Average]
```

The rules for the results of decimal arithmetic are rather convoluted.  In general, with division, the results often have greater precision than the inputs.

If `TimeToAnswer` is an integer, then SQL Server does integer arithmetic.  I would simply do:

```
  CAST(AVG(TimeToAnswer*1.0) AS Decimal(10, 2)) as [Average]
```

Comment: I tried that but got inaccurate results. I've posted it as an EDIT in my question.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT datepart(year,CallStartTime) [Year]
      ,datepart(month,CallStartTime) [Month]
      ,datepart(day,CallStartTime) [Day]
      ,CAST(AVG( (TimeToAnswer)) AS Decimal (10,2)) [Average]

FROM LineCallTracer LCT

WHERE LCT.CallStartTime >= '2017-10-01 00:00:00.000'
  AND LCT.DNIS = 5050
  AND LCT.MainDevice IS NOT NULL

GROUP BY datepart(year,CallStartTime), 
    datepart(month,CallStartTime), 
    datepart(day,CallStartTime)

ORDER BY [Year], [Month], [Day]
```

Comment: I tried that but got inaccurate results. I've posted it as an EDIT in my question.

Comment: try this : SELECT .....
      ,round(TimeToAnswer,2) AS [Average] or try cast as double

Answer (score 1):

Use `FORMAT` to display a number in a desired format (e.g. with two decimal places):

```
FORMAT(AVG(TimeToAnswer), '#########0.00') AS [Average]
```

Comment: I tried that but got inaccurate results. I've posted it as an EDIT in my question.